# Remove Items in Entity Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

How to remove items in Entity Collection?

ex:

I have two entities that is related to each other

Employee and Reference

```
**Table: Employee**

EmployeeId(PK) 

**Table: Reference**

ReferenceId(PK)
EmployeeId(FK)
Name
```

first I Initialize this:

```
Employee empCol = new Employee();
Reference refs = new Reference();
```

and then I save some data in the Entity Collection

```
refs.Name = "Sample";
empCol.References.Add(refs);

refs.Name = "Sample2";
empCol.References.Add(refs);
```

I want to remove the second element in the collection, how can I do that?

```
[0]= {Name = "Sample"}
[1]= {Name = "Sample2"}
```

I try this kind of code but it is not working, this code does not removing the second element in my Entity Collection, but it is not producing errors:

```
empCol.References.ToList().RemoveAt(1);
```

Comment: Is any of this saving to the database at any point? It's hard to understand your question.

Comment: No, I will not save it yet to the database, I need first to save the data to Entity Collection I am thinking of this scenario: what if the user want to remove the data that he entered, before he save it to the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont assume how `index` is maintained inside by `collection`. Find the object `first`, and then `remove` it from `collection`

```
var ref = empCol.References.FirstOrDefault( r=> r.Name == "Sample");
if (ref != null)
    empCol.References.Remove(ref);
```

If you want to remove by `index`, Find that index first.

Comment: If ref is null, an exception will be thrown on your first line. Use FirstOrDefault instead. Also, for string variables, it is preferable to use String.Equals instead of ==

Comment: @Tilak - What do you mean by "index", is that the primary key or the it's index in the collection?

Comment: It is index in the collection (realized through [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

I try to remove the object in the collection according to it's **`index`** in the collection and it work

```
var refs = empCols.References.ElementAt(1);
empCols.References.Remove(refs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use all the List methods to remove items if you convert your EntityCollection into a List using toList(), for example

```
 List<RotateArticle> articles = RotateArticle.GetDataByCategoryId(sm,currentArticle.MainCategory.Key).ToList();
```

and then

```
articles.Remove(articles[i]);
```

or

```
articles.RemoveRange(2, articles.Count - 1);
```